# one query for two purposes

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have the following two queries:

A.

```
db.query(DBHelper.TABLE, new String[] {
                DBHelper._ID, DBHelper._DATE_AND_TIME,
                DBHelper._SOURCE, DBHelper._MODE,
                "SUM(" + DBHelper._AMOUNT + ")" },
                DBHelper._DATE_AND_TIME + " BETWEEN ? AND ?",
                new String[] { date_min, date_max }, null, null, null, null);
```

and result of sum goes to textview like this

```
 String.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)).
```

Second query B.

```
db.query(DBHelper.TABLE, new String[] {
            DBHelper._ID, DBHelper._DATE_AND_TIME,
            DBHelper._SOURCE, DBHelper._MODE,
            DBHelper._AMOUNT }, DBHelper._DATE_AND_TIME
            + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", new String[] { date_min, date_max },
            null, null, null, null);
```

and result goes to

```
 adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from,
            to, FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY);
```

What I want is to combine both queries. Close cursor after first query and to use same query (A) for adapter. So far I have added DBHelper._AMOUNT to SELECT of A query but ListView shows only the last entry result (not the whole data). How can I modify query A for showing SUM in TextView and then use same query for adapter.

Comment: Very thankful for editing my question but can someone answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal query (like B), the database returns a result record for each table record that matches the WHERE filter.

However, when you are using an aggregate function like SUM(), the database computes a single value from all table records (or from all records in a group if you're using GROUP BY) and returns that as a single result record.

Therefore, your two queries are fundamentally different and cannot be combined into a single query.

(Please note that the first four result columns of your query A do not have any meaningful value because the result record is not guaranteed to correspond to any particular record in the original table; you should ask only for the SUM value.)

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this for me. I assume there are some possibilities to do it (by using aliases for example) but my current knowledge of database and query techniques are not so good. Please confirms if it is possible even theoretically. Thanks again.

Comment: If columns selected in query A do not have any meaningful value does it mean that use of aggregate function in SELECT constrict query only with result function returns. Sorry if too many questions asked.

Comment: A query returns a fixed number of columns, and a specific number of rows, so it is not possible to change the result without changing the query. When using aggregate functions, you can use the values of table columns only as arguments to aggregate functions, or when they have been constricted to a single value (for a specific result row) by GROUP BY.

Comment: OK. I've got it. Otherwise Dr.Hipp could call it queries when created. Thank you again.